# Is there a way to write null coalescing operator in curlybrackets in php

Tags: php

I get a code like this for example

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `news` where `id`={$_GET['4545645463']??null}";
```

is there any way that I can use null coalescing operator  in curlybrackets in

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `news` where `id`={@$_GET['4545645463']}";
```

both can't be accepted by php is there anyway that I can use null safe operator in curly brackets

Comment: Before that, you should use [SQL prepared statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: ^This is the only valid solution. FYI if the paramater is not set, then why even bother executing the query? I can't imagine any records having an id that is `null`. You are just creating overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try it like this:

```
// @var int|null $id 
$id = $_GET['news_id'] ?? null;

if ($id) {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE `id` = ?";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
     $stmt->execute();
}
```

The approach you are trying to take here leaves you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)!

Also, no, just put an if check if there is something that might be null.

Answer (score -1):

I did prepare $sql first then execute like this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `news` where `id`={$_GET['id']}";
$statement=$conn->prepare($sql)
$statement->execute();
$variables=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I take the code above as example sometimes I need to write null safe operator in string
maybe not in sql but a php string variable

also very thank you for answer to avoid SQL injection I think I'll never write sql string with php variable inline

Comment: This is not how you avoid sql injection though... It's not because you are using a prepare that you are safe for the injection if you still just use the variable directly in the query. You need to use placeholders as seen in [runtimeTerror's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72458802/446594)

Comment: It's seems you are using `PDO`, then you would need to use `bindParam` or pass the placeholder in the execute. More information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: I would try bindParam next time to avoid sql injection